# Why won't my error message show when a filter returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a test shop with some basic filters, but I want to display an error message if one or more of the filters returns empty. If you click on the (this will not work) button you will see an empty page but want the error message to show there, the error message shows up on the index but not on the empty page as needed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let message = $("p");
message.hide();

$('.filter-list button').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');

   let filterArr = $(".filter-list button.active").map(function() {
       return $(this).data('filter');
   });

   let filterItem = $(".item");

   if(filterArr.length <= 0) {
       filterItem.show();
       message.show();
   } else {
       filterItem.hide();
       message.hide();
       filterItem.each(function () {
           for(let i = 0; i < filterArr.length; i++) {
               if($(this).hasClass(filterArr[i])) {
                   $(this).show();
               }
           }
       });
   }
});
$('.clear-all').click(function() {
    message.hide();
    $('.filter-list button').removeClass('active');
    $(".item").show();
});
```

```js
let message = $("p");
message.hide();

$('.filter-list button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  let filterArr = $(".filter-list button.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('filter');
  });

  let filterItem = $(".item");

  if (filterArr.length <= 0) {
    filterItem.show();
    message.show();
  } else {
    filterItem.hide();
    message.hide();
    filterItem.each(function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < filterArr.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(filterArr[i])) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
$('.clear-all').click(function() {
  message.hide();
  $('.filter-list button').removeClass('active');
  $(".item").show();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: arial;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.content-control {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap md-5">
  <h1>Test shop filters</h1>
  <div class="content-control filter-control">
    <div class="filter-list">
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter1">Filter 1</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter2">Filter 2</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter3">Filter 3</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter4">Filter 4</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter6">This will not work</button>
    </div>
    <button class="clear-all">Clear all</button>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item filter1">filter1</div>
      <div class="item filter1">filter1</div>
      <div class="item filter2">filter2</div>
      <div class="item filter2">filter2</div>
      <div class="item filter3">filter3</div>
      <div class="item filter3">filter3</div>
      <div class="item filter4">filter4</div>
      <div class="item filter4">filter5</div>
      <div class="item filter5">filter5</div>
    </div>
    <p>Error this filter does not exist</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, use `.filter()` to get all the items that match the class you're filtering with. Then you can test the length of this to see if it matches anything, and display an error message if not.

```js
let message = $("p");
message.hide();

$('.filter-list button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  let filterArr = $(".filter-list button.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('filter');
  });

  let filterItem = $(".item");
  filterItem.hide();
  message.hide();
  filterArr.each((i, filter) => {
    let theseItems = filterItem.filter(`.${filter}`);
    if (theseItems.length == 0) {
      message.show();
    } else {
      theseItems.show();
    }
  });
});

$('.clear-all').click(function() {
  message.hide();
  $('.filter-list button').removeClass('active');
  $(".item").show();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: arial;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.content-control {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap md-5">
  <h1>Test shop filters</h1>
  <div class="content-control filter-control">
    <div class="filter-list">
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter1">Filter 1</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter2">Filter 2</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter3">Filter 3</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter4">Filter 4</button>
      <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="filter6">This will not work</button>
    </div>
    <button class="clear-all">Clear all</button>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item filter1">filter1</div>
      <div class="item filter1">filter1</div>
      <div class="item filter2">filter2</div>
      <div class="item filter2">filter2</div>
      <div class="item filter3">filter3</div>
      <div class="item filter3">filter3</div>
      <div class="item filter4">filter4</div>
      <div class="item filter4">filter5</div>
      <div class="item filter5">filter5</div>
    </div>
    <p>Error this filter does not exist</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that worked! Thank you so much. I see what you did with the edits and noted for future future,